# Beautify/reformat the SQL script button partially working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am making my way through *Murach's MySQL, 2nd Edition* and I've encountered a bit of a speed bump.

When writing scripts to create tables, etc., I've always been able to write scripts and with the cursor at the end, press the `Beautify/reformat the SQL script button` and they get cleaned up.

With the following code, it only gets partially cleaned up (just the `SELECT` statement). The following code does what it's supposed to, but the Beautify/reformat button doesn't clean up everything in the editor. Any suggestions?

```
use ap;

drop procedure if exists test;

delimiter //

create procedure test()
begin
declare first_invoice_due_date date;

SELECT 
    MIN(invoice_due_date)
INTO first_invoice_due_date FROM
    invoices
WHERE
    invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total > 0;

if first_invoice_due_date < now() then
select 'Outstanding invoices overdue!';
elseif first_invoice_due_date = now() then
select 'Outstanding invoices are due today!';
else
select 'No invoices are overdue.';
end if;
end//
```

Comment: Hi Adrian! I'm not entirely sure this question is a valid fit for dba.se. It's interesting but we don't really focus on tools for things like beautifying code. Sadly it's not really a fit for anywhere on the StackExchange network. It's the sort of thing that's gonna go stale pretty quickly and very few people are unlikely to need it in the future. Additionally see this link, it seems to apply: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65523

Comment: @jcolebrand Thank you. I did see that link and noticed it was originally from 2012. I had hoped someone figured out a workaround for those of us too lazy to press shift/caps lock.

Comment: I usually use something like Notepad++ and one of the SQL reformatters, or just try to keep my formatting by myself instead of relying on a tool, which is a bit like saying "surely you can ride a unicycle, I can" and not really super empathetic, sorry. It's just a practice that you have to get into. I'm digressing. Maybe there are some other tools that can help outside of that editor tho if you need them formatted for a good reason? Otherwise, I would just suggest that as you're learning, rigor and ritual are more important than tools. Sorry I'm not much help.

Comment: @jcolebrand I appreciate your input. I was going to delete the Q, but I'd like to avoid the wrath of Rick James, as he posted an answer. http://gph.is/1a6sAIf

Comment: haha, no need to delete, it's just not a good fit. We can let it lie.

Comment: Solution: It seems this is a known bug (5 years and counting) in the currently shipping version of MySQL Workbench. I was able to resolve it using the following plugin in Sublime Text 3: http://code.mteixeira.me/SQLTools/

Answer (score 1):

Bug:  `NOW()` is to the second.  You probably want `CURDATE()`, which is midnight this morning.  And would work nicely if `first_invoice_due_date` were declared `DATE`.

Avoid Cursors!  They are a speed bump.  Instead, learn how to write SQL statements that do everything all at once.

(As for beautifing, your code is prettier than most of the stuff on this forum!)